# How to use homebrew to get avidemux

Tags: macos, git, repository, homebrew

When I do `brew search avidemux` it says this.

> No formula found for "avidemux". Searching open pull requests...
>   https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/8429

If I go to that page I can see that it has avidemux.

So how do I get it?

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
brew install https://raw.github.com/2bits/homebrew/ea94454957414936c2591d398f80d0627f1dc339/Library/Formula/avidemux.rb
```

Comment: How did you get that address?

Comment: The file is contained in the last commit referred to in the github issue.